# How to find intervals in the domain corresponding to intervals in the range?

Tags: plotting, functions

I want to find the intervals for the argument `m1` of this function corresponding to the value for the function lying in given intervals of the range:

```
F1==Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1/m1^2 + 20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
   3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 24304810001/50^2 + 
   623602/(m1* 50)] - 10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - 155900/50]
```

and graph for this function is:

[image]

For example I want to find the range of intervals of `m1` when I divide a given range for `F1` into 10 equal intervals. How do I tell the software to divide a range into 10 equal interval and give the corresponding intervals for `m1`?

Comment: THis might be along the lines of what you want. `In[231]:= Quiet[
 Table[m1 /. FindRoot[f1 == j, {m1, 100}], {j, .2, .1, -.01}]]

Out[231]= {50.1792464866, 55.6107747091, 61.9743927038, \
69.4962425108, 78.4754522385, 89.3143417388, 102.564285935, \
118.997248446, 139.72082195, 166.369869733, 201.43913107}`

Comment: In this problem I want to divide the axis for f1 to equal intervals and find the corresponding amount for m1 axis. if I want to explain more, I want to find equal interval in Y axis(f1) rather than X axis(m1). its problem because all function are define to find intervals for X axis intervals.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I dont know which method did you used? but your method just divide until 100, I want to start from 50 to 400, In this problem I want Y axis intervals be same but X axis interval different and corresponding to Y axis

Comment: The code I show has equal y axis intervals of 1/100. It then computes the corresponding endpoints of the x (actually m1) axis intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Solve`.

```
f1[m1_] := Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1/m1^2 + 20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
       3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 
       24304810001/50^2 + 623602/(m1*50)] - 
       10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - 155900/50];
```

Define a minimum, maximum and resolution for the interval, here I used small values so that the interval lines show up in the plot:

```
{min, max, n} = {.1, .3, 10};
int = Range[min, max, N[(max - min)/n]];
sol = m /. Solve[f1@m == #, m] & /@ int // Flatten;
Plot[f1@m1, {m1, 0, 400}, Epilog -> {Dashed, Opacity@.5, 
   MapThread[Line@{{0, #1}, {#2, #1},  {#2, 0}}&, {int, sol}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, .5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Thread[int -> sol]  (* f1 -> m1 *)
```

> ```
> {0.1 -> 201.439, 0.12 -> 139.721, 0.14 -> 102.564, 0.16 -> 78.4755, 
>  0.18 -> 61.9744, 0.2 -> 50.1792, 0.22 -> 41.4569, 0.24 -> 34.8259, 
>  0.26 -> 29.6673, 0.28 -> 25.5754, 0.3 -> 22.2752}
> ```

Comment: thank you so much, its the answer and its right.

Comment: Dear i want to apply this code but it gives me errore in mapthread line

Comment: @aghil123 There was a typo at one line end (`l` instead of `;`), corrected now. Please check.

Comment: it was corrected but actually my equation is too long when I applied this method I wait for long time but didn't get answer. do you have any idea for long equations??? maybe use NSolve or NDsolve instead of Solve???

Answer (score 1):

If

```
f1=Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1/m1^2 + 20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
   3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 24304810001/50^2 + 
   623602/(m1* 50)] - 10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - 155900/50]
```

then

```
Limit[f1, m1->0]
(* \[Infinity] *)

min=Limit[f1, m1->Infinity]
(* 1/5 Sqrt[-155900 + Sqrt[24304810001]] *)
```

therefore you'll need to consider an upper limit, say 2 :

```
max = 2
```

Then you can generate the intervals as :

```
intervals = Partition[Range[min, max, 0.5], 2, 1] ;
```

and solve for the corresponding ranges for `m1` :

```
sol = Reduce[{#[[1]] <= f1 <= #[[2]], m1 <= 1000}, m1, Reals] & /@  intervals
```

Comment: this plot is to find m1 VS f1. I want to devide f1 to 10 equal intervals from 50 to 400 and find the corresponding values for m1 in X axis. I dont know why when I Run your method in the last part gives error and dont give explicit and clear intervals for m1??